# how to modify path's order according to the x axis when using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, stacked-chart

I want to draw a stacked area graph which can show the tendency and the value.

For example:
data:

```
year,orange,apple
1976,30,20
1980,20,40
1988,50,30
```

related code:

```
stack = d3.stack()
      .order(d3.stackOrderAscending)
      // .order(order)
      .keys(keys);

series = stack(data);

area = d3
  .area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(new Date(d.data.year, 0, 1));
  })
  .y0(function(d) {
    return yScale(d[0]);
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  });

$ele
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(series)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'area')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + template.padding + ',0)')
  .attr('d', area)
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return get_colors(i);
  });
```

It shows like this:

The current result
[image]
But what I want to do is to put the max value on the top (according to the x axis's value)of the graph
[image]
And therefore the order of the categories will change with the x axis.

I tried to define my own order function,but it only return an array which seems to define only a order, which means the order can not change.

I hope you can understand what I said.Thanks！！！

Comment: you have to write the stacking yourself, start by using the series as created by `stack()`. Result: https://i.imgur.com/TjKwy9Z.png

Comment: Yeah! I succeeded it as you said! Thanks！